# JavaScript creating HTML5/XML element node

Tags: javascript, html, dom, createelement

To create an element to be used in a HTML5 document with JavaScript we can use the createElement() and createElementNS() methods from DOMDocument objects:

```
var node = document.createElement(element);
var node = document.createElementNS(nameSpace, element);
```

These commands create a node and than we can put it at some point of the document tree using `appendChild()`. My first question is: do the `document.createElement()` and `document.createElementNS()` functions store the node object they return at some place in the `document` object?

Second, is it possible to create an element node object (possibly using a name space) independent of specific `document` objects and later on to append it in the document tree of some `document`object given? That is, are there functions similar to `createElement()` and `createElementNS()` which are not members of a specific object (like the `document` object, as is the case above)?

Third, is it possible to create an element node object using a given document object `document1` and them to append it on the document tree of another document object `document2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My first question is: do the document.createElement() and document.createElementNS() functions store the node object they return at some place in the document object?

No, the implementation may do something like that internally, but nothing like that is exposed externally.

> is it possible to create an element node object (possibly using a name space) independent of specific document objects and later on to append it in the document tree of some documentobject given?

The answer to this question is also no: each element, in general, each node is bound to the document object used to create it, which is referenced by the `ownerDocument` property.

> Third, is it possible to create an element node object using a given document object document1 and them to append it on the document tree of another document object document2?

Yes, the second document has to *adopt* the node, via the [`adoptNode`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#Document3-adoptNode) method. With DOM4 this method will mostly become unnecessary, since it's primarily used before insert a foreign node in a document, and [DOM4 specifies](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-core) that the adoption in such case is implicit.

Comment: Thank you Carlos! Just to put it clear, about the first two questions, we have a `ownerDocument` property wich refers to the document used to create the element node object, but the document object itself has neither a pointer to the element node object created nor an array containing all element node objects created using it. Did I understand it right?

Comment: Exactly, if it isn't inserted in the tree, there's no way to get it, knowing only the owner document. If I answered correctly your question, please don't forget to accept it.

Comment: Thank you again! Yes, my question was completely answered and I've just accepted it. Unfortunately, I am new to stackoverflow and I do not have sufficient reputation to tag it as useful, but it was very useful.